# If list index exists, do X

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my program, user inputs number `n`, and then inputs `n` number of strings, which get stored in a list.

I need to code such that if a certain list index exists, then run a function.

This is made more complicated by the fact that I have nested if statements about `len(my_list)`.

Here's a simplified version of what I have now, which isn't working:

```
n = input ("Define number of actors: ")

count = 0

nams = []

while count < n:
    count = count + 1
    print "Define name for actor ", count, ":"
    name = raw_input ()
    nams.append(name)

if nams[2]: #I am trying to say 'if nams[2] exists, do something depending on len(nams)
    if len(nams) > 3:
        do_something
    if len(nams) > 4
        do_something_else

if nams[3]: #etc.
```

Comment: Looks like you want to type cast `n` as an integer, not a list.  I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, the real problem here is using `n` instead of `nams` in the `if`s

Comment: In your case n is not a list. First check (cast) it to be an integer, then you could iterate or enumerate depending on the effect you want to achieve.

Comment: Yep, mistyped. Fixed to nams[]

Comment: "the fact that I have sub if statements about len(my_list)." Have you thought about what is implied about which list indices exist, by the fact that the `len` of the list is at least a certain value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if the n-th element exists in a Python list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554255/how-to-check-if-the-n-th-element-exists-in-a-python-list)

Comment: @wedi this question was asked in 2012 that one in 2013, so actually it is the other way around **for others: No, there is no hasIndex/isset in Python for lists** you must go with `len()` or `IndexError` exception checking, not sure why it wasn't implemented straight away, but that's just how things are... refs:   https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Could it be more useful for you to use the length of the list `len(n)` to inform your decision rather than checking `n[i]` for each possible length?

Comment: Yep. Upon reviewing the code, my set-up was completely superfluous; len(n) accomplished everything I needed. Thanks for a point in the right direction.

Comment: This doesn't account for negative indexes. The best way I know is try / except IndexError, but it'd be nice to have a concise way to get a bool

Comment: In Python negative indexes on lists just count backwards from the end of the list.  So they could not exist in a way that impacts the length of the list.

Answer (score 120):

*I need to code such that if a certain list index exists, then run a function.*

This is the perfect use for a [try block](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

```
ar=[1,2,3]

try:
    t=ar[5]
except IndexError:
    print('sorry, no 5')   

# Note: this only is a valid test in this context 
# with absolute (ie, positive) index
# a relative index is only showing you that a value can be returned
# from that relative index from the end of the list...
```

However, by definition, all items in a Python list between `0` and `len(the_list)-1` exist (i.e., there is no need for a try block if you know `0 <= index < len(the_list)`).

You can use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) if you want the indexes between 0 and the last element:

```
names=['barney','fred','dino']

for i, name in enumerate(names):
    print(i + ' ' + name)
    if i in (3,4):
        # do your thing with the index 'i' or value 'name' for each item...
```

---

If you are looking for some defined 'index' though, I think you are asking the wrong question. Perhaps you should consider using a [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) container (such as a dict) versus a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) container (such as a list). You could rewrite your code like this:

```
def do_something(name):
    print('some thing 1 done with ' + name)
        
def do_something_else(name):
    print('something 2 done with ' + name)        
    
def default(name):
    print('nothing done with ' + name)     
    
something_to_do={  
    3: do_something,        
    4: do_something_else
    }        
            
n = input ("Define number of actors: ")
count = 0
names = []

for count in range(n):
    print("Define name for actor {}:".format(count+1))
    name = raw_input ()
    names.append(name)
    
for name in names:
    try:
        something_to_do[len(name)](name)
    except KeyError:
        default(name)
```

Runs like this:

```
Define number of actors: 3
Define name for actor 1: bob
Define name for actor 2: tony
Define name for actor 3: alice
some thing 1 done with bob
something 2 done with tony
nothing done with alice
```

You can also use [.get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method rather than try/except for a shorter version:

```
>>> something_to_do.get(3, default)('bob')
some thing 1 done with bob
>>> something_to_do.get(22, default)('alice')
nothing done with alice
```

Comment: try block? I am a beginner in Python but this seems like a big no no in programming...exceptions for flow control? Exception should be for things we cannot control right?

Comment: @Luis I'm a beginner in Python as well, but from what I've read exception handling in these instances is the style Python promotes that C/Java/C# don't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python

Comment: The sentence 'all indices in a Python list between 0 and len(list)' is absolutely wrong. Let's say there's a list x = [1, 2, 3] which len_x = 3. There is no such index as 3.  The sentence should have been: 'all indices in a Python list between 0 and len(list) - 1'.

Comment: @LiorMagen: You are right and I edited it. That is kinda harsh to down vote a fairly popular post for such a pedantic error. A simple comment would suffice.

Comment: I'll point out that sticking things inside a `try` does *not* tell you if the index exists just if it is fetchable - take `-1` - that index doesn't really *exist* but a value would be returned.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Point taken, but this is a bit like Clinton's *“It depends on what the meaning of the word ‘is’ is.”* In this context, it depends on the meaning of *exists* and if that meaning is different for relative vs absolute indices.

Comment: @dawg yup, I'm not downvoting or anything, but do suggest making an edit to explicitly state that. This answer is popping up for "determine if an index is in a list" searches (which is how I ended up here) and depending on what they want, it might introduce a subtle bug that won't be caught easily (again, what happened to me - but not your fault, I found this after *after* I realized the bug)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Say more about the specific edit suggested. If edited to clarify that this only applies to positive (non-relative) indices, would that have clarified this for you before your bug?

Comment: Hmm I have the rep to just edit, but that seems rude. I would say something like `*Note* that this approach will work whenever a value *can be looked up* by a specific index from the list. This is not quite the same as if an index exists. You can for example fetch the value at -1 (the last item) but that index does not exist. To check if an index exists use 0 <= n < len(lst)`

Comment: I added a comment to the code example that addresses your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

It can be done simply using the following code:

```
if index < len(my_list):
    print(index, 'exists in the list')
else:
    print(index, "doesn't exist in the list")
```

Answer (score 22):

`len(nams)` should be equal to `n` in your code. All indexes `0 <= i < n` "exist".

Answer (score 8):

Using the length of the list would be the fastest solution to check if an index exists:

```
def index_exists(ls, i):
    return (0 <= i < len(ls)) or (-len(ls) <= i < 0)
```

This also tests for negative indices, and most sequence types (Like `ranges` and `str`s) that have a length.

If you need to access the item at that index afterwards anyways, it is [easier to ask forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp), and it is also faster and more Pythonic. Use `try: except:`.

```
try:
    item = ls[i]
    # Do something with item
except IndexError:
    # Do something without the item
```

This would be as opposed to:

```
if index_exists(ls, i):
    item = ls[i]
    # Do something with item
else:
    # Do something without the item
```

Answer (score 7):

> I need to code such that if a certain list index exists, then run a function.

You already know how to test for this and in fact **are already performing such tests in your code**.

The valid indices for a list of length `n` are `0` through `n-1` inclusive.

Thus, a list has an index `i` **if and only if** the length of the list is at least `i + 1`.

Comment: Yep, I had the tools to solve my problem, just wasn't applying them clearly. Thanks for a point in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for this, especially the last sentence, which is an important property of Python lists that make them different from JavaScript arrays and other similar constructs.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate the inserted actors data:

```
for i in range(n):
    if len(nams[i]) > 3:
        do_something
    if len(nams[i]) > 4:
        do_something_else
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, so I think it's actually possible (for the sake of argument):

```
>>> your_list = [5,6,7]
>>> 2 in zip(*enumerate(your_list))[0]
True
>>> 3 in zip(*enumerate(your_list))[0]
False
```

Comment: though this would be even simpler:
`3 in range(len(your_list)`

Comment: or even this `3 in xrange(len(your_list)` - probably can't do better than this

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
list = ["a", "b", "C", "d", "e", "f", "r"]

for i in range(0, len(list), 2):
    print list[i]
    if len(list) % 2 == 1 and  i == len(list)-1:
        break
    print list[i+1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner:

```
do_X() if len(your_list) > your_index else do_something_else()
```

Full example:

```
In [10]: def do_X(): 
    ...:     print(1) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [11]: def do_something_else(): 
    ...:     print(2) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [12]: your_index = 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [13]: your_list = [1,2,3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [14]: do_X() if len(your_list) > your_index else do_something_else()                                                                                                                                                                      
1
```

Just for info. Imho, `try ... except IndexError` is better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple, if computationally inefficient way that I felt like solving this problem today:

Just create a list of available indices in my_list with:

```
indices = [index for index, _val in enumerate(my_list)]
```

Then you can test before each block of code:

```
if 1 in indices:
    "do something"
if 2 in indices:
    "do something more"
```

but anyone reading this should really just take the correct answer from: @user6039980

Answer (score -5):

Do not let any space in front of your brackets.

Example:

```
n = input ()
         ^
```

Tip:
You should add comments over and/or under your code. Not behind your code.

---

Have a nice day.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your reply looks like a comment rather than an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). If you intended to Answer, read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to follow the SO guidelines.