# How to check if the n-th element exists in a Python list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python

```
x = ['a','b','c']
```

with 3 elements. I want to check if a 4th element exists without receiving an error message.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 29):

You check for the length:

```
len(x) >= 4
```

or you catch the `IndexError` exception:

```
try:
    value = x[3]
except IndexError:
    value = None  # no 4th index
```

What you use depends on how often you can *expect* there to be a 4th value. If it is usually there, use the exception handler (*better to ask forgiveness*); if you mostly *do not* have a 4th value, test for the length (*look before you leap*).

Comment: Nice, you showed a new user both the LBYL and EAFP patterns. (@A_B, google them)

Comment: That’s fine if the number your testing is a known fixed value, but if it’s an integer variable you might not want to accept negative values as valid, though they will successfully index into the list.

Comment: @SimonHibbs or normalise the value first (add `len(x)` to negative indices, so `normalised = len(x) + idx if idx < 0 else idx`), then check if `0 <= normalised < len(x)`.

Answer (score 4):

You want to check if the list is 4 or more elements long?

```
len(x) >= 4
```

You want to check if what would be the fourth element in a series is in a list?

```
'd' in x
```