# Checking if the next element in a python list is empty

Tags: python, list, peek

So what I am trying to accomplish is to check whether an element is empty by using a counter + 1 but I keep getting index out of range which essentially means the next element doesnt exist, but instead of throwing an exception I want the program to return a boolean to my if statement is that possible..? In essence I want to peek forward to the next element of a tuple within a dictionary actually and see if it is empty.

```
>>> counter = 1
>>> list = 1,2,3,4
>>> print list
>>> (1, 23, 34, 46)
>>> >>> list[counter]
23
>>> list[counter + 1]
34
>>> list[counter + 2]
46

>>> if list[counter + 3]:
...     print hello
... else:
...     print bye
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: That's tuple not a list. Can you not use a for/while loop?

Comment: Have you tried the `len` function?

Comment: By *empty* do you mean "doesn't exist"?

Comment: Yes by empty I mean doesn't exist apoologies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If list index exists, do X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786157/if-list-index-exists-do-x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use try/catch to catch error if you index a not available index of a list

And the main thing it is a bad practice to name variable with keywords i.e. list,set etc

```
try:
    if list[counter + 3]:
        print "yes"
except IndexError:
    print 'bye'
```

Comment: "Easier to ask forgiveness than permission."

Answer (score 3):

You can use `len` to check for whether you are within the range.

For example:

```
>>> l = 1,2,3,4
>>> len(l)
4
```

Also, a tuple is not a list. It is generally considered bad practice to name things as `list` or `array` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check presence of index in tuple or list is to compare given index to length of it.

```
if index + 1 > len(my_list):
    print "Index is to big"
else:
    print "Index is present"
```

Comment: This is wrong for python 3 at least. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 code without exceptions:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
print(f"Lenght of list: {len(my_list)}")
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    print(f"We are on element: {index}")
    next_index = index + 1
    if next_index > len(my_list) - 1:
        print(f"Next index ({next_index}) doesn't exists")
    else:
        print(f"Next index exists: {next_index}")
```

Prints this:

```
>>> Lenght of list: 3
>>> We are on element: 0
>>> Next index exists: 1
>>> We are on element: 1
>>> Next index exists: 2
>>> We are on element: 2
>>> Next index (3) doesn't exists
```