# Check if user input is equal to an item's index in list

Tags: python

I'm just wondering if it's possible to see if the users input equals an item's index within a list?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
data = ['hello', 'hi', 'hey']

user_choice = int(input("Enter 1,2 or 3: ")
user_answer = user_choice - 1
if user_answer in ....: # How would I finish this off line off?
    result = data[user_answer]
    print(result)
```

Comment: `if 0 <= user_answer < len(data)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If list index exists, do X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786157/if-list-index-exists-do-x)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data = ['hello','hi','hey']

user_choice = int(input("Enter 1,2 or 3: ")
user_answer = user_choice - 1
if user_answer in range(1,len(data)+1): #just give length of data
    result = data[user_answer]
    print(result)
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, it will fail if we input `1` and it's also inefficient. Instead use `if 0 <= user_answer < len(data)` as suggested in the comments by mkrieger.

Comment: @RoyCohen i did notice this to so i changed it but forgot to mention it in here. Thanks for noting this for others who check this question

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to put `[1,2,3]` or `range(1,4)` in your blank space.

```
data = ['hello','hi','hey']

user_choice = int(input("Enter 1,2 or 3: "))
user_answer = user_choice - 1
length = len(data)+1
if user_answer in range(1,length): #How would i finish this off line off?
    result = data[user_answer]
    print(result)
```

Results:

```
Enter 1,2 or 3: 2
hi
```